# Gradle : should I launch build everytime before run?

Tags: gradle

I want to know is it necessary that everytime I fetch some new commits from remote repo, I should do a build before the run ? Or is it enough to launch the run directlt ?

Comment: Which platform are you talking about? An Android project? A JVM project? A Spring project?

Comment: Yes for a Spring project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your run task depends on the "assemble" task then Gradle will do the right thing. It will recompile if any dependent file has changed. If nothing has changed Gradle will use its up-to-date checking to skip all the compile, jar etc tasks.